# Roll the dice using JS and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use the `setTimeout` function to create a `rollthedice` function but instead of 6, I have 10 numbers.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Roll Dice</title>

<style>

button {
    padding: 16px 24px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <button class="roller" onclick="rollTheDice()">Roll</button>
    <h2 class="number">0</h2>
    
</body>

<script>

    function rollTheDice() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
        document.querySelector(".number").innerHTML = x; 
        setTimeout(rollTheDice, 1000); 
    }

   
</script>

</html>
```

This goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Onur selamlar, rollTheDice fonksiyonu içinde `setTimeout(rollTheDice, 1000)` yazarak, loop'u oluşturmuş oluyorsun aslında. Eğer loop'a girmesini istemiyor isen, o satırı kaldırarak, loop'u engellemiş olursun =)

Comment: O zaman şöyle bir yol izleyebilirsin; 1- rollTheDice fonksiyonu çalıştığında roller butonunu disable et, 2- içeride setInterval ile çalışacak counter'ı olan bir değişken oluştur, set interval içine verilen fonksiyonu verilen sürede çalıştıran bir fonksiyon, 3- her setinterval fonksiyonu çalıştığında counter'ı arttır, 4- counter limite ulaştığında( if(counter === 5) { clearInterval(timer);  } ) diyerek interval'i sil. Her saniye dönecek interval içinde de random bir sayı oluşturup bu sayıyı innerHTML içine yazabilrisin =)

Comment: Eğer kurguyu oluşturamaz isen yanıt olarak da yazabilirim sonrasında :)

Comment: abi çok sağol ama kodu yazabilirsne ordan daha iyi anlamaya çalışabilriim zahmet olmassa zira daha başlayalı 2-3 hafta oluyor :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `counter` variable to pre-determine how many numbers will be shown before the wheel stops:

```
<button class="roller" onclick="counter=20;rollTheDice()">Roll</button>
```

and then decrease `counter` and only call `setTimeout` if the `counter` is greater than 0.

```
if (--counter>0) setTimeout(rollTheDice, 100);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Roll Dice</title>

<style>

button {
    padding: 16px 24px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <button class="roller" onclick="counter=20;rollTheDice()">Roll</button>
    <h2 class="number">0</h2>
    
</body>

<script>

    function rollTheDice() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
        document.querySelector(".number").innerHTML = x; 
        if (--counter>0) setTimeout(rollTheDice, 100); 
    }

   
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Solution ,

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1 ;
```

& Here's explanation ,
Math.random() generates random number from 0.000* - 1
Math.floor() rounds up that number to nearest integer
If that random number is 1 then whole expression gives 6 ie. max
Otherwise less than that but not 0 bcoz 1 is Always added
Hope you will understand

Comment: Hi Niirmaal. Thanks for the help but what I am looking for is to see the numbers run like a vending machine for couple of seconds and then see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it to stop after 10 times.
so i would count the number of times it's run and set a target amount, and only reset the Timeout if it hasn't reached that target number.

```
function loop(i){
    let rolls = 0;
  rollTheDice()
  
  function rollTheDice() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
    document.querySelector(".number").innerHTML = x; 
    rolls++;
    if(rolls < i) {
      setTimeout(rollTheDice, 300); 
    } 
  }
}
    
loop(10) // set the target rolls
```